# use std::function in schedule

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2d-x for a while, there is a problem constantly boring me:
I want delay executes a function such as "void f(int a)" by schedule. But for cocos2d-x, it can not pass a variable on stack:

int a = 10;
// call f(a) in delay

Of course I can use CCInteger, CCxxx, but it was too painful to do it. It just a copy of cocos2d, really troublesome in cpp.

So, is there a easy way let it to executes a std::bind(f, a)?

Comment: schedule(schedule_selector(GameScene::GameLoop), 0.5f); try this for scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try c++11 feature , here is the code by my self:

**Define CallbackHelper Class**

```
class CallbackHelper : public CCObject
{
private:
    std::function<void ()> _func;
public:
    static CallbackHelper* create(std::function<void ()> func) {
    CallbackHelper* ret = new CallbackHelper();
    if (ret) {
        ret->autorelease();
    } else {
        CC_SAFE_DELETE(ret);
    }
        ret->_func = func;
        return ret;
    }
    void run() {
        _func();
    }    
};
```

**Make CCCallFunC:**

```
int a = 10;
CallbackHelper* callback = CallbackHelper::create([a](){
    cout<<a<<endl;
});
CCCallFunc::create(callback, callfunc_selector(CallbackHelper::run));
```

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-x 3.0 has entered beta - it supports c++11, nad you can use lambda expressions in schedule methods - here is quite a comprehensive tutorial about them : http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html

Anyhow: what was painfull about using CCInteger or other cocos classes to pass the data? They were designed to do it. What are you trying to achieve in the end? Maybe passing a whole node would be a better idea?

Comment: CCInteger like class is stupid in cpp, even cocos2dx don't use it. try to invisible a sprite in delay, the parameter is bool, you can't pass it